# Difference between the FBX 6.1.0 and 7.1.0 specifications?

Tags: animation, export, blender, fbx

I'm using Blender to export bone animations to the FBX file format, for consumption by Assimp. The latest version of Assimp supports FBX versions 7.1.0 through 7.3.0 ([See lines 298-301](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/FBXDocument.cpp)). Blender exports to version 6.1.0.

Is there a major difference between 6.1.0 and 7.1.0?

I'm wondering if I can just manually edit the exported file and change the version to 7.1.0, just to make Assimp happy.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of blender now has an update FBX-exporter. The specific changes can be found here 
http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/06/supporting-game-developers-with-blender-2-71/

The old version had problems with smoothing groups and including animations, besides many other points. If Assimp can read the new FBX you may want to give it a try.